# Applescript: Changing fonts of Photoshop text object- resulting in cut off text

Tags: excel, fonts, applescript, photoshop

I am using the values from Microsoft Excel for Mac 2016 and photoshop CC 2017 to automate creating the text of a person's name + their ID number along with their associated photo within Photoshop. When I go to change the text:

```
tell application "photoshop cc 2017"
--some code
    set font of text object of art layer 1 to "GothamRounded-Bold"
```

Part of the value specifically, the last name gets cut off. My question is: Is this a known bug? Or what am I doing wrong? Here is the sourcing of the cells from Excel:

```
tell application "Microsoft Excel"


            --this gets the full name of a person from a cell
            set fullname to value of column 1 of row u of sheet 1 of active workbook as text
            --this gets the person's id number
            set personid to value of column 2 of row u of sheet 1 of active workbook as text
            --this removes the .0 from the excel value
            set num to first character of personid
            --this combines the two to make the caption
            set idfullname to num & space & fullname
```

For instance,

what should be "3 Will Morris", gets reformatted as "3 Will". However, if I leave it in the default font: Myriad Pro, the full name and number get sourced perfectly. I've also tried using some delays, to no avail. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Perhaps it's just a simple difference between Point Text & Paragraph Text, as Point text doesn't do any automatic wrapping